# Outlook 2010 signature: Add to contacts link

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

I want to know if we can add a link in outlook 2010 signature so when it's clicked by the recipient, outlook adds the sender's contact details into their contact.

Eg: I send you an email with my email signature in it. My signature would contain a link which reads "Add contact to address book" and when you click this link, my contact details should be added into your address book.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You or the sender need to add your own details & email address to the Contacts in Outlook (Contacts > New Contact)

Then
2. Open a New Email like you're sending and put the cursor under the signature where you want to enter the contact details
3. In the Include tab click the Insert Business Card icon, in the drop-down arrow select the Contact you have just added. (Contacts become Business Cards )

You should now see the Business card added.

1. If you are the sender, if you send the email the recipient should see the business card. #
2. All they have to do then is Right-Click and the Add to Outlook Contacts

Give it a shot and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to build an add-in that would be loaded in the recipient's Outlook instance. The add-in would then need to work with events of the opened message to determine what was clicked and what to do when a link is clicked.  I believe for this specific scenario you'd actually need to work with the Word Object Model (because that's the render engine) or perhaps the HTMLDOM to trap link clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You could link it to a .vcf file (vcard), which the user could then download enabling them to save your contact details.

Comment: The answer above does that in Outlook 2010